# Alternative Source for Downloading OTB Dataset for Visual Object Tracking

Tags: dataset

I'm interested in downloading the OTB dataset for visual object tracking. The official site (http://cvlab.hanyang.ac.kr/tracker_benchmark/index.html) appears to be down. Does anyone know of alternative sources or mirrors where I can obtain this dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an archived copy at the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20221118171918/http://cvlab.hanyang.ac.kr/tracker_benchmark/index.html

Comment: It works for me.
Thank you very much. :-)